# Wording of approved tag wiki edits in achievement dialog is confusing

Tags: feature-request, tag-wiki, achievements-dialog, wording

Today I suggested a *Tag Wiki* and a *Tag Wiki Excerpt* for [shared-accounts](/questions/tagged/shared-accounts).

They where both quickly approved, leading to a confusing situation in my achievements dialog. Can we please distinguish between both events in their achievement dialog message?

[image]